# How to Convert image (.png) to base64 string, vice a versa and strore it to a specified location

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm trying to store images (png) to sqlite database in a windows 8 app, and i figured out it can be done by converting it to base64 string and storing the string to the database. Later on in the app i want to convert that base64 string to png image and store it to a specified location. The Problem is i don't know how to convert images to base64 and base64 to image and store it to a specified location in c# windows 8 app. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

```cs
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
  }
}

public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        return Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @HardLuck...Looks good, in the second method, shouldn't the MemoryStream be initialized in a using block just to be sure it is disposed properly?

Comment: @hardluck how to store the image to a specified location in the app say asset folder of the app?

Comment: If the image is going to be static consider using resources or a folder in a solution, otherwise it should be in DB. If you need to write it to the file system than just use:  `Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(typeof(Button), "Button.bmp");

    // Save the image as a GIF.
    bmp1.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);`

Comment: @HardLuck i tried the above code but sadly the windows 8 store apps does not support the System.drawing dll so any features related to is not supported as well