# How to get the attached image in your view and convert it to base64 in Xamarin Mvvm

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a project that captures the image using camera.

After capturing the image it will display in my view.

what I need to do is to get the attached image in my view and convert it to Base64.

My View:

```
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Label x:Name="CaptureLabel" Text="Capture Image:" TextColor="Black" FontSize="12" Margin="20,10,0,0" 
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Label>

            <Image x:Name="CameraButton" Margin="20,5,15,0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

        </StackLayout>
```

My Code Behind:

```
    private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var photo = await Media.Plugin.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Media.Plugin.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() { });

        if (photo != null)
            CameraButton.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return photo.GetStream(); });
            CameraButton.HeightRequest = 80;
            CameraButton.WidthRequest = 50;

            MainStack.HeightRequest = 470;

    }
```

Comment: Convert it while you still have access to it via your `photo` instance.

Comment: Do you have any steps on how to convert and image to base64 in xamarin?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can also see this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874733/converting-image-to-base64` and this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089359/how-to-convert-image-png-to-base64-string-vice-a-versa-and-strore-it-to-a-sp`.